# RTK Query wait for isSuccess and set state

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I have an edit post form that I want to close ONLY when mutation was successful.

So given i have a component

```typescript
function PostForm({ post, setIsEditing }) {
  const [editPost, { isLoading, isError, isSuccess }] = useEditPostMutation();

  return (
    <form onSubmit={() => handleSubmit(data)}>
      ...
    </form>
  );
}
```

What is the correct approach?

Doing it inside a useEffect hook with isSuccess in the dependency array:

```typescript
useEffect(() => {
  if (isSuccess) setIsEditing(false);
}, [isSuccess]);
```

Or wait for the response and check if it was successful:

```typescript
  const handleSubmit = (data) => {
    editPost(data)
    .then(res => if (isSuccess) setIsEditing(false));
  }
```

Maybe there is some other preferred way of doing stuff like this?

Comment: This is a rather subjective question and probably not on-topic for Stackoverflow. The preferred method is the one that works best for you. IMHO I would recommend the second version using the Promise chain or `async/await`. Is there a specific issue you have with either implementation we could help resolve?

Comment: If this question is not appropriate for Stackoverflow, then I am sorry, but I just wanted to know the preferred way of doing it and maybe discover something else I was missing. You just assured me that my way of thinking was correct and that it is just a matter of preference. Thank you for the response!